# Simple code to view and save the image in the database

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've been developing a website, I came across the difficulty of saving an image in the database.

Through forums on the internet I got this code from the first `<form>`.
This code is almost perfect but it only has one thing, this code saves the direct image in the database as soon as it receives the instruction to send from within the first `<form>`.
In this method if the user selects 1000 images is to click on send, the server will accept the instruction without any filter.
So I need to find a way for the user to select an image on his device, click on send, that image will appear as a preview on the screen, and only send it to the server when all the data in both forms is inserted.

I already developed the action of the second `<form>`, in it I receive via post all data from the label, and the variable `$nameimag` is saved in MySQL.
When I need to display it i would search the database would use `echo '<div> <img src = "./ images /'. $ nameimag. '" width = "200"> </div>';`.

**Code here:**

```php
<?php 
  // Start session, check login/logout
  session_start(); 

  if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
    header('location: login.php');
  }
     
  if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION['username']);
    header("location: login.php");
  }   
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheetini.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      jQuery('document').ready(function() {
        jQuery('#ajax_form').submit(function() {
          var dados = jQuery(this).serialize();
          // aqui voce pega o conteudo do atributo action do form
          var url = $(this).attr('action');
          jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: dados,
            success: function(response) {
              //'response' é a resposta do servidor
              alert(response);
            }
          });
          return false;
        });
      });
    </script>
    
    <style type="text/css">
      .choose::-webkit-file-upload-button {
        color: white;
        display: inline-block;
        background: #cc00cc;
        border: none;
        padding: 7px 15px;
        font-weight: 700;
        border-radius: 3px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 10pt;
      }

      .box1 {
        height: 20px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 3px #9900cc;
      }
      .filediv {
        text-align: center;
      }

      .choose {
        box-shadow: 0 0 3px #9900cc;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header"></div>

    <div class="content">
      <!-- Notification message -->
      <?php if (isset($_SESSION['success'])) : ?>
        <div class="error success">
          <h3>
            <?php 
              echo $_SESSION['success']; 
              unset($_SESSION['success']);
            ?>
          </h3>
        </div>
      <?php endif ?>
    
      <!-- Form -->
      <?php  if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) : ?>
      <div>
        <div class="buttonaling">
          <div class="container">
            <form method="POST" id="limpar" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <label for="conteudo" class="textopaginacadastro"> imagem:</label>
              <div class="filediv">
                <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*" multiple class="choose">
              </div>

              <?php if(isset($_FILES['pic'])) {
                $ext = strtolower(substr($_FILES['pic']['name'],-4)); 
                $nameimag = date("Y.m.d-H.i.s") . $ext; 
                $dir = './imagens/'; // Diretório para uploads

                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'], $dir.$nameimag); //Fazer upload do arquivo
                echo '<div> <img src="./imagens/' . $nameimag . '"  width="200"> </div>';
              }?>
    
              <div align="center">
                <button type="submit"  class="inic1">Send image</button>
              </div>
           </form>
         </div>
    
         <form method="post" action="validarcadastro.php" id="ajax_form">
            <label class="text1">data1</label>
            <input type="text" name="item" class="box1">
    
    
            <label class="text1" >data2</label>
            <input type="text" name="descricao" class="box1">
    
            <button type="submit" class="inic1" id="btn1" >Salve</button>
         </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php endif ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Why you've added two versions on JQuery?

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to use a canvas element and JavaScript to take the image from the file input and display it directly. This way the image is only sent to the server with all the other fields. So this approach only uses 1 form and does not use ajax to post the extra data, all data plus image is sent to server together.

The following is a very simplified version with no styling etc but it shows the theory mentioned above:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <label for="imageInput">Select Image:</label>
      <input type="file" id="imageInput" accept="image/*"/><br/>
      <canvas id="myCanvas" width="10" height="10"></canvas>
      <br/><br/>

      <label class="text1">data1</label>
      <input type="text" name="item" class="box1"/><br/><br/>


      <label class="text1">data2</label>
      <input type="text" name="descricao" class="box1"/><br/><br/>

      <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
    </form>

  </div>
  <script>
    //Taken from https://www.educity.app/blog/how-to-upload-and-draw-an-image-on-html-canvas
    const imgInput = document.getElementById('imageInput');
    imgInput.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
      if (e.target.files) {
        let imageFile = e.target.files[0]; //here we get the image file
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(imageFile);
        reader.onloadend = function (e) {
          let myImage = new Image(); // Creates image object
          myImage.src = e.target.result; // Assigns converted image to image object
          myImage.onload = function (ev) {
            let myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas"); // Creates a canvas object
            let myContext = myCanvas.getContext("2d"); // Creates a contect object
            myCanvas.width = myImage.width/2; // Assigns image's width to canvas (scaled by half)
            myCanvas.height = myImage.height/2; // Assigns image's height to canvas (scaled by half)
            myContext.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0, myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height); // Draws the image on canvas
          }
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You would need to test for browser and device compatibility.